# Finding parametric representations fo the parts of the plane

Tags: parametrization

How would I find parametric representations for the plane:
$2x+3y+z=4$ for $0 \leq x + y + z \leq 7$ and $2 \leq x-y \leq 4$?
I can do simple ones where only $x,y$ are restricted independently (forms a rectangle in the $x-y$ plane, but how would I go about doing this one (when all three variables are involved)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x-y=u$ and $x+y+z=t$. Then you can find $x$, $y$ and $z$ in terms of $u$ and $t$ by Crammer's Rule.

$$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{2u-t+4}{3},\frac{-u-t+4}{3},\frac{-u+5t-8}{3}\right),$$

where $2\le u\le 4$ and $0\le v\le7$.

Comment: I'm not very familar with Cramer's rule. Is this do-able with just row reduction?

Comment: $4-t=(2x+3y+z)-(x+y+z)=x+2y$. So $(x+2y)-(x-y)=4-t-u$ and hence $3y=4-t-u$. With $y$, you can find $x$ and then $z$.

Comment: Thanks. This is for linear systems. What if I had the condition that $x \geq 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$ which is non-linear?

Comment: Maybe you can let $x=t$, $z=u$ and express $y$ in terms of $t$ and $u$. Rewrite the condition $x^2+y^2\le 4$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: So something like $x^2 + y^2$ = $(x+y)^2 - 2xy$?